# Android OpenCV memory leak

Tags: java, android, opencv, kotlin, video

I am working on an app that uses opencv to process video.

This is the opencv part of my function:

```
 //Open the streams
    var merged = VideoCapture()
    merged.open(file.path)
    var flicker = VideoCapture()
    flicker.open("$cacheLocation/flicker.avi")
    var grain = VideoCapture()
    grain.open("$cacheLocation/oldgrain.avi")

    //Check if all streams are opened
    if (!merged.isOpened || !flicker.isOpened || !grain.isOpened){
        Log.e("OpenCVHelper", "One or more streams did not open, ABORT!")
        throw Exception()
    }

    val videoWriter = VideoWriter()
    videoWriter.open("$location/$fileName", VideoWriter.fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), merged.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FPS), Size(merged.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), merged.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))

    //Setup variables
    var totalFrames = merged.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
    var grainFrames = grain.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
    var flickerFrames = flicker.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
    var grainCounter = 0
    var flickerCounter = 0

    //Setup mat's
    var frameMat = Mat()
    var rgbaFrame = Mat()
    var whiteAlphaMat = Mat.ones(Size(merged.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), merged.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)),0)
    whiteAlphaMat.setTo(Scalar((255).toDouble()))
    var videoTmpMat = mutableListOf<Mat>()
    var videoRgbaMat = mutableListOf<Mat>()
    var flickerMat = Mat()
    var grainMat = Mat()
    var tmp = Mat()
    var alpha = Mat()
    var rgb = mutableListOf<Mat>()
    var rgba = mutableListOf<Mat>()
    var flickerAlphaMat = Mat()
    var grainAplhaMat = Mat()


    for(frameCounter in 0..totalFrames.toInt()){
        System.gc()
        //Set the position of the readers
        merged.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frameCounter.toDouble())
        grain.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, grainCounter.toDouble())
        flicker.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, flickerCounter.toDouble())

        //Create material of the current frame
        merged.read(frameMat)

        //Create an rgba mat of the frame

        videoTmpMat.clear()
        Core.split(frameMat, videoTmpMat)
        videoRgbaMat.clear()
        videoRgbaMat.add(videoTmpMat[0])
        videoRgbaMat.add(videoTmpMat[1])
        videoRgbaMat.add(videoTmpMat[2])
        videoRgbaMat.add(whiteAlphaMat)
        Core.merge(videoRgbaMat, rgbaFrame)

        //Create the overlay materials
        flicker.read(flickerMat)
        grain.read(grainMat)

        //Create rgba of the overlays
        rgb.clear()
        rgba.clear()

        Imgproc.cvtColor(flickerMat, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        Imgproc.threshold(tmp, alpha, (100).toDouble(), (255).toDouble(), Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY)
        Core.split(flickerMat, rgb)
        rgba.add(rgb[0])
        rgba.add(rgb[1])
        rgba.add(rgb[2])
        rgba.add(alpha)

        Core.merge(rgba, flickerAlphaMat)

        //tmp = Mat()
        //alpha = Mat()
        //rgb = mutableListOf()
        //rgba = mutableListOf()
        rgb.clear()
        rgba.clear()

        Imgproc.cvtColor(grainMat, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        Imgproc.threshold(tmp, alpha, (100).toDouble(), (255).toDouble(), Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY)
        Core.split(grainMat, rgb)
        rgba.add(rgb[0])
        rgba.add(rgb[1])
        rgba.add(rgb[2])
        rgba.add(alpha)
        Core.merge(rgba, grainAplhaMat)

        //Apply blur to the frame
        Imgproc.blur(rgbaFrame, rgbaFrame, Size((8).toDouble(),(8).toDouble()))

        //Apply flicker to the frame
        Core.addWeighted(rgbaFrame, 1.0, flickerAlphaMat, 0.5, 0.0, rgbaFrame)

        //Apply grain to the frame
        Core.addWeighted(rgbaFrame, 1.0, grainAplhaMat, 0.5, 0.0, rgbaFrame)

        //Add a title
        Imgproc.putText(rgbaFrame, "Made with Super8Life", Point(10.0, 1050.0), 7, 2.0, Scalar(255.0,255.0,255.0), 2);

        //Write frame to file
        videoWriter.write(rgbaFrame)

        //Clear up memory
        //frameMat.release()
        //flickerAlphaMat.release()
        //flickerMat.release()
        //grainAplhaMat.release()
        //grainMat.release()
        //videoTmpMat.forEach {
        //    it.release()
        //}
        //videoRgbaMat.forEach {
        //    it.release()
        //}
        //whiteAlphaMat.release()

        //Handle the counters
        Log.d("OpenCVHelper", "Frame: $frameCounter")
        //val percentage = frameCounter.toDouble() / totalFrames * 100.toDouble()
        //Log.d("OpenCVHelper", "$percentage%")

        if (grainCounter < grainFrames -1){
            grainCounter ++;
        } else {
            grainCounter = 0;
        }
        if (flickerCounter < flickerFrames -1){
            flickerCounter ++;
        } else {
            flickerCounter = 0;
        }
    }
    videoWriter.release()
```

It eats up memory 4 of the 5 times of testing the app and that causes the app to crash:
[image]

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong? I have already moved the declaration of the Mat's outside the loop. Mat.release() doesn't do anything

thx a lot,
Jules

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/5715

Comment: Any solution? Thx

Comment: According to the issue tracker, this is a bug within OpenCV that hasn't been solved since 2015. If your issue is caused by this bug, then a possible solution would be to acquire images via another method. Maybe you can check if the the memory leak is, indeed, caused by `videoCapture()`. Try reading a static image from disk and see if memory consumption is still increasing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=20q-rZzNROY) and change my manifest.xml to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.myopencvandroid">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front.autofocus" android:required="false"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My RAM memory have 60MB used !!!